CRBasic with NodeJS, socket connection sometimes disconnected
I am trying to write program code to make my datalogger (CR1000X) send data to my NodeJS server, here is my server code:
const net = require('net');

// Tạo server TCP
const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
  console.log('Client connected:', socket.remoteAddress, socket.remotePort);

  socket.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('Hex Data:', data.toString('utf-8'));
  });

  socket.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Client disconnected');
  });
  socket.on('error', error => {
    console.log('Client disconnected', error);
  });
});

const PORT = 6785;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

It's just simple to get the data from the datalogger. But sometimes, I saw the log Client disconnected :
Client disconnected Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:216:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}

but I dont know how to solve this on datalogger size, here is my CRBasic code:
BeginProg
  Socket = TCPOpen(IP_Addr,PORT,3)
  CPISpeed(250)            '250 kbps, how fast the datalogger will operate the CPI bus.
  'This value may need to be adjusted based on the number of
  'VWIRE 305 modules and the total cable length.  Refer to the
  'VWIRE 305 quick start guide for more information.

  Scan(5, msec, 500, 0)    '200 Hz / 5 msec scan rate
    CDM_VW300Dynamic(CPIAddress, Freq(), Diag())   'Get dynamic readings
    CallTable DynamicFreq

    If TimeIntoInterval(0,1,Sec) Then ' Process static data only once per second
      CDM_VW300Static(CPIAddress, StaticFreq(), Therm(), DynStdDev()) 'Get static data
      CallTable OneSecData

      OutString = FormatFloat(Freq(1), "%f")
      OutString = OutString & "," & FormatFloat (Freq(2), "%f") 

      For i = 1 To 2
        OutString = OutString & "," & FormatFloat (Therm(i), "%f") 
      Next

      If Socket > 0 Then
        SerialOut(Socket, OutString, 0, 1, 0)
      End If
    EndIf
  NextScan

EndProg

My purpose is catch socket problem/error on CRBasic, then connect again + send data
I tried to search on CRBasic site, but I can not find the way to solved this

What is your analysis. Can you set the even on error to trace the error log? ALso did you tried disabling the setTimeout. Also Ensure the SerialOut command in your CR1000X program is correctly configured to send data over the TCP connection.

can u provide me the way to get error log? I dont know how to do it

Add this line socket.on('error', error => {console.error(Socket error: ${error.message});});

i tried to using UDP method, can u take a look?https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79296035
